# The Network Adapter could not establish the connection error but telnet works

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to connect to database using the VIP for the DB servers . I can connect to DB using this VIP from my local machine.

From the unix box I cannot connect using this VIP

Here is my JDBC URL

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@scan01.usatln6.db.net:1521/CF
```

**Error**

```
IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

When I replace this VIP with real IP of DB I can connect.

However the telnet to this VIP works fine

```
$ telnet scan01.usatln6.db.net 1521
  Trying 10.96.36.252...
  Connected to scan01.usatln6.db.net.
  Escape character is '^]'.
  Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found success with a JDBC connect string formatted as such:

```
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname.com:1521/orcl.dbname.local", "user", "pass");
```

So, try adding two slashes after the "@" sign.